# jquery mobile - Event binding issue on page load

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using jquery mobile for my website. If the page is loaded for the first time it works fine. If the page is loaded though ajax (with transition) it won't works. I tried with pageinit event and no success.

This is the footer script which is included in all the pages.

```
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="expand-footer" class="expand-button" data-role="none"></a>
    <div class="footer-content"> Footer </div>

    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#expand-footer').unbind("click").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("click");
        $('#expand-footer').toggleClass('expand-button-close', 'expand-button');

        if ($('#expand-footer').hasClass('expand-button expand-button-close')) {
            console.log("if click");
            $('.footer-content').hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
        } else {
            console.log("else click");
            $('.footer-content').show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
        }

    });
   });
```

What could possibly be the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think you should listen to `unbind`. Naturally, I would listen for the `click` event:

```
$('#expand-footer').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("click");
    $('#expand-footer').toggleClass('expand-button-close', 'expand-button');

    if ($('#expand-footer').hasClass('expand-button expand-button-close')) {
        console.log("if click");
        $('.footer-content').hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
    } else {
        console.log("else click");
        $('.footer-content').show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
    }
});
```

If the mobile site will be used on a device, then you would need to add an event listener for when the device is ready `document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);` and if you need this code to be used all the time, then execute it when the device is ready.

```
function onDeviceReady(){
    $('#expand-footer').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("click");
        $('#expand-footer').toggleClass('expand-button-close', 'expand-button');

        if ($('#expand-footer').hasClass('expand-button expand-button-close')) {
            console.log("if click");
            $('.footer-content').hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
        } else {
            console.log("else click");
            $('.footer-content').show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
        }
    });  
}
```

If however, you need the code to execute when the user navigates to a certain page only, then you can use any one of the following methods:

- pageshow
- pagecreate
- pageinit

More documentation can be found here: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html

Your syntax would then be as follows:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#your_page_id', function(){
    $('#expand-footer').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("click");
        $('#expand-footer').toggleClass('expand-button-close', 'expand-button');

        if ($('#expand-footer').hasClass('expand-button expand-button-close')) {
            console.log("if click");
            $('.footer-content').hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
        } else {
            console.log("else click");
            $('.footer-content').show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
        }
    });   
});
```

To use the other events:

```
$(document).on('pagecreate', '#your_page_id', function(){
    //your code here
});

$(document).on('pageshow', '#your_page_id', function(){
    //your code here
});
```

`.live` also works but will soon be deprecated:

```
$('#your_page_id').live("pagecreate", function(){
     //your code here
});
```

To dynamically append the id using JavaScript:

```
$(document).append('<div data-role="page" id="your_page_id"><div data-role="content">dummy text</div></div>'); $('#my_page_id').page();
```

Or in your PHP file:

```
<?php
    echo "<div data-role=\"page\" id=\"your_page_id ";
    //use single quote ' to avoid escaping double quote in string
    echo " \"></div>";
?>
```

TO AVOID A SPECIFIC ID: Alternatively, you can apply the jQuery to any page using:

```
$(document).on('pagecreate','[data-role=page]', function(){
    //code here
});


$(document).on('pageinit','[data-role=page]', function(){
    //code here
});


$(document).on('pageshow','[data-role=page]', function(){
    //code here
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick reply. In my case, each page is new php file which is loaded dynamically on clicking the link. How can i identify the '#your_page_id', where this is the footer script which is common to all over the site.

Comment: or again using javascript                         $(document).append('<div data-role="page" id="my_page_id"><div data-role="content">FOO BAR</div></div>');
$('#my_page_id').page();

Comment: Hi, The page has been loaded by clicking the following link.

<a class="logincls" href="/users/signin" data-transition = "slide">LOGIN</a>

data-role=page divv is generated automatically.

I have tried with pageinit event and still having issue.

Thanks

Comment: Are you making sure your page is appended to DOM?  var myid = $('#your_page_id'); $(body).append(myid); And also that it is defined? http://www.hardcode.nl/archives_139/article_191-jquery-check-if-dom-element-exists.htm if(myid.length >0){           //execute your code} http://api.jquery.com/append/ If my answer works for you please accept/upvote

Comment: Hi , Yes, It is generating automatically but without id. Actually it is not mobile device site. It is desktop browser application. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, It works. I have assigned page id to the <div id="<current page name>" data-role="page"> dynamically for each page while loading, and also appending random number to expand-footer id (ie expand-footer-<random>).